# Error Creating Bundles M2.4.2: The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "tier_price" component

Tags: admin, magento2.4, bundled-product

I have never created a bundle item before, and upon trying to create a new bundle today, I receive the error: The `componentType` configuration parameter is required for the `tier_price` component.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

> main.CRITICAL: The `componentType` configuration parameter is required
> for the "tier_price" component.
>
> {"report_id":`"956c444dc2e28e84ff3f6abe968fab576f82c509d2d961deaa2f09456fc672f4"`,"exception":`"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0)`: The
> "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the
> `tier_price` component. at
> `/chroot/home/a65fd1e2/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:405`

Answer (score 1):

Little late answer, but I was facing the same issue today after data migration to 2.4.3.

I had a custom attribute set and inside them, the `tier_price` attribute was missed inside the Advanced pricing tab which caused the issue.

Hope this helps.

[image: missing tier_price attribute]